# How to set exit popup when if any changes occurs and try to move to other page

Tags: jquery

I have tried form serialize and checked if any other changes have done while clicking on the "cancel" button. Now I need, the popup should occur even when any navigation occurs.

```
var global=$("#form").serialize();
function cancelfunction(){
    if(global!=$("#form").serialize()))
        {//popup triggers }}
```

With Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create a boolean flag to indicate if anything was changed, and on every input type change, trigger it to true, while on save set it to false. on page unload check on its value.

Usually you'd achieve that like:

```
alert('you have unsaved data!');
```

But,browsers are blocking alerts on `beforeunload`, so you need to do it like this instead:

```
return 'you have unsaved data!';
```

[**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/L3Lwy8j6/1/)

**CODE:**

```js
// Initializing, this will set an initial value of false to the flag changeNoSave.
var changeNoSave;


// on change event of eachinput type we need to check on, we set the flag to true
// as change without submit has happened.
$('.checkMe').on('change', function() {
  changeNoSave = true;
});

$('#submitBtn').on('click', function(e) {
  //e.preventDefault() just for demo, not part of the solution
  e.preventDefault();
  
  //we set our flag to false again, as change has happened but saved upon form submit
  changeNoSave = false;
  console.log('you can leave the page safely');
});


$(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
  // on before unloading the page, we check ifchanges happend but not saved , or like
  // if changeNoSave = true, we alert by the return line
  if (changeNoSave) {
    return 'you have unsaved data!';
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" class="checkMe">
  <input type="text" class="checkMe">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chkbx" class="checkMe">
  <label for="chkbx">Test</label>
  <select class="checkMe">
    <option value="1">option 1</option>
    <option value="2">option 2</option>
    <option value="3">option 3</option>
  </select>
  <button id="submitBtn">submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But I need Custom alert ,not the default browser alert.

Comment: It's the same, `if (changeNoSave) { showCustomALert(); }` and that's it

Comment: Well it turned out that you need to `return` browser alert, because it'll navigate away anyways even if you show the custom alert https://jsfiddle.net/vq98ztcq/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In the above example,we are getting the custom alert,thats fine.But I do not need the browser alert.In this case, compulsorily we have to return some values for the "beforeunload" function. Is it any option to use our custom alert alone???..

Comment: in the fiddle in my last comment I tried to to use the custom alert alone, it will be called if data changed without submit, and the custom alert appears, but the browser will navigate away ignoring the custom alert because it is a popup or a modal rather than a browser alert. so it will navigate away even though the custom alert is shown